# pass list of expressions into filter/select

Tags: r, tidyeval

I'm interested in writing a function that returns a data frame with a default subset on its rows and columns.

I can get the following code to work:

```r
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

default_cols <- quos(mpg, cyl, vs)
default_filters <- quos(mpg > 20, cyl == 6)

my_filter_select <- function(
  filters = default_filters, 
  selects = default_cols
) {

  mtcars %>%
    filter(!!! filters) %>% 
    select(!!! selects)
}

my_filter_select()
#>    mpg cyl vs
#> 1 21.0   6  0
#> 2 21.0   6  0
#> 3 21.4   6  1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

But adding to the default seems to be cumbersome as I would have to use `append(default_filters, quos(<filter-expr>))`.

I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do this.

I tried the following by passing the default filter and select expressions as list (presumably an easier interface) and it crashes:

```r
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

default_cols <- function() list(mpg, cyl, vs)
default_filters <- function() list(mpg > 20, cyl == 6)

my_filter_select2 <- function(
  filters = default_filters(),
  selects = default_cols()
) {
  fff <- enquos(filters)
  sss <- enquos(selects)

  mtcars %>%
    filter(!!! filters) %>%
    select(!!! selects)
}

my_filter_select2()
#> Error in default_filters(): object 'mpg' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

So the goal is to somehow pass lists as arguments into the function which will eventually be evaluated in either the `filter` or `select`.

Comment: Use `quos()` instead of `list()` in the default functions.

Comment: Any idea on best practices to append defaults? Right now I'd have to use `append(default_filters(), quos(...))`, which works, but I'm unsure if that is a good practice.

Comment: I'm not sure defaults are best practices. But I can see how they could make sense to reduce code duplication within a particular script. But yes, if you like `append()`, that's a fine way of combining lists of defused inputs.